# Presence of TabRow triggering HorizontalPager to recompose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, jetpack

Dealing with a situation that I do not have enough knowledge of Compose to rectify.

I have a TabRow with a HorizontalPager beneath it. For some reason, the mere presence of the TabRow causes the HorizontalPager to recompose even when the page is changed by a swipe and not a tap on the TabRow.

As soon as I comment out the TabRow, the HorizontalPager stops recomposing no matter how many times I swipe.

I genuinely have no clue why this would be happening.

Here is the Tab code:

```
val pagerState = rememberPagerState(pageCount = {
    2
})
val selectedTabIndex = remember { derivedStateOf { pagerState.currentPage } }
val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()
Column(modifier = Modifier
    .height(60.dp), verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center) {
    TabRow(selectedTabIndex = selectedTabIndex.value, modifier = 
        Modifier.fillMaxHeight(), containerColor = Color.White, contentColor = 
        Color(0xFF000000)) {
        tabTitles.forEachIndexed { index, title ->
            Tab(
                text = { Text(text = title, fontSize = 18.sp, color = Color(0xFF000000),
                    fontFamily = FontFamily(Font(R.font.tfont))) },
                selected = selectedTabIndex.value == index,
                onClick = {
                    coroutineScope.launch { pagerState.animateScrollToPage(index) }
                })
             }
         }
     }
}
```